# Javascript this inside this.method

Tags: javascript, constructor

```
var AnimationManager = function (time, completionMethod) {
    "use strict";
    this.animationObjects = [];
    this.time = time;
    this.add = function (animationObject) {
        this.animationObjects.push(animationObject);
    };
    this.completionMethod = completionMethod;
    this.currentStage = 0;
    this.maximumStage = this.time * FPS;

    this.tick = function () {
        this.currentStage += 1;
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < this.animationObjects.length; i += 1) {
            this.animationObjects[i].applyAnimation(this.currentStage);
        }

        if (this.currentStage < this.maximumStage) {
            console.log(this.currentStage);
            setTimeout(this.tick, 1000.0 / FPS);
        } else {
            this.completionMethod();
        }
    };

    //Call this to start
    this.startAnimation = function () {
        this.timer = setTimeout(this.tick, 1000.0 / FPS);
    };
};
```

The chrome console is saying this.animationObjects is undefined but I set it to an empty array. why is this?

Comment: Where are you using this code? At the moment it's just a function declaration and doesn't do anything at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context for `this.tick` is lost when you pass it as a timeout handler. Use:

```
 this.timer = setTimeout(this.tick.bind(this), 1000.0 / FPS);
```

Or the slightly old-fashioned:

```
 var mgr = this;
 this.timer = setTimeout(function() { mgr.tick(); }, 1000.0 / FPS);
```

The value of `this` is determined upon each call to a function. There's no inherent long-term relationship between a function and any particular object; in other words, the fact that the "tick" function was originally created as the value of a property of that object really doesn't matter. What matters is how the function is *called*.